# Inserting values into a table and delete rows based on a condition using merge in snowflake

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table with DBName, SCName, Number. I wrote a procedure that inserts the DBName, SCName into the table and deletes a row when a Number is 0. I used merge to avoid duplicates and insert based on the condition but I don't understand how to delete a row when a Number=0.

```
------------------------
|DBName| SCName| Number|
|  DB1 |  SC1  |   1   |
|  DB2 |  SC2  |   0   | <-- Need to delete row
|  DB2 |  SC3  |   2   |
|  DB2 |  SC1  |   4   |
|  DB3 |  SC4  |   0   | <-- Need to delete row
------------------------
```

Here is my Procedure:

```
CREATE TABLE TABL(DBName VARCHAR, SCName VARCHAR); // creating table

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE repo(DB VARCHAR,SC VARCHAR) 
    RETURNS string
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$      
        //inserting values into table using merge
        //if values are already present and Number = 0 then I need to delete row
        var sql_command = `merge into TABL as t 
                            using (SELECT :1 as database,:2  as schema) as s 
                            on t.DBName = s.database 
                            and t.SCName = s.schema 
                            when matched then update 
                            set t.DBName = t.DBName 
                            when not matched then insert 
                            (DBName, SCName) VALUES (:1,:2)`;
        snowflake.execute({sqlText: sql_command, binds: [DB, SC]});

    return 'success';
    $$;
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't understand in which case (MATCHED / NOT MATCHED) the rows with '0' should be deleted from the target table.

But in general you have only can use DELETE in the MATCH-case:

```
when matched and number=0 then delete
```

It is important to avoid a nondeterministic result for the merge (see link below under "Duplicate Join Behavior"). Solution therefor is to also add "and number!=0" to your "when matched then update"-clause.

More infos: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/merge.html

EDIT: I posted wrong information. For MATCH you can Delete and Update, for NOT MATCH you can INSERT.

Comment: I'm using update function to update the changed rows and during update process if I find that table contains a row with Number=0 then I need to delete that whole row

Comment: Then you have to add "when matched and number=0 then delete" after the update-clause and add "and number!=0" to the update-clause. As said above :)

Comment: I'm getting a syntax error when I wrote `when not matched then insert (DBName, SCName) VALUES (:1,:2) WHEN NOT MATCHED and Number=0 THEN DELETE`. Can you tell me where I'm going wrong

Comment: the column "number" has to be a column in your target-table

Comment: Marcel, So there can be two `not matched` statements right?

Comment: Sorry, I posted wrong information above. My fault. DELETE is only possible within the MATCH-clause and here you can have more than one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222335/discussion-between-r0bert-and-marcel).